# Why is the British government waiting until March 29th to officially Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, article-50

A few days ago the Brexit bill received royal assent, the last official step required for a UK bill to become law. The UK has declared that they will officially invoke Article 50 on March 29th, 9 days from when I'm writing this.

Why the delay? Why not just declare it now. I'm presuming there is some operational or technical reason why they need another 9 days, but I do not know it.

Comment: I think it's just time for preparation for both the UK Gov & the EU Com. It would quite rush and unexpected if they suddenly notify the EU to trigger Article 50.

Comment: @Panda Right, but preparation of what specifically? I mean this has obviously been going to happen for almost a year now, plus once its triggered there is a 2 year long clock. I'm curious about what specifically is the cause of this wait.

Comment: The British press have suggested that it's to avoid invoking Article 50 during the week of celebrations of the 60th anniversary of the signing of the Treaty of Rome on the 25th, but I can't find an authoritative source for that.

Comment: The cynic in me thinks that Mrs May is well aware how much work is ahead of them, and the 29th gives her another 9 days to do preliminary work, without being right up against the deadline she set herself.

Comment: It's the last month end before the end of the tax year on April 5th. I don't think that's very relevant but it makes as much sense as any other guesswork..

Comment: I don't think the announcements made by Nicola Sturgeon about independence can be ignored as a factor either.

Comment: Isnt it March 29, 2019?

Comment: Because 29 March 2019 is a Friday, and it means the first day when Britain will re-take control of its own laws, borders and money will be the the following Monday, which happens most appropriately to be ALL FOOLS DAY!

Answer (score 7):

March 29th is the Friday before the 1st of April, the new financial year. That gives financial institutions the weekend to calm their nerves, get IT systems up and running and make a "clean" break on the first day of the new financial/tax year.

Of course the plan is to have a transition period during which nothing much changes, so this may be an unimportant date for financial institutions with the projected end of the transition on December 31st 2021 being the big change-over.

Then again, if there is a no-deal brexit the 29th of March will be the cliff edge and the government will use the weekend to try to prevent Monday being a huge financial crash.

Arguably 9 days was not enough, the government might have done better to make it a year and 9 days to give itself time to prepare a negotiation strategy, but the weekend falling just before April 1st seemed to present an opportunity.

Comment: I like the explanation in your first paragraph, but is it true?  Is there a stated intent this date was chosen for this reason?  Do you have a source for it, or is it just speculation?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple reasons, but one that typically gets overlooked is it will allow financial firms extra time to prepare - they would need to do a rather large workload of stuff (run special reports, talk to clients, potentially update configurations and models).

This doesn't just affect "rich bankers" - it will also potentially affect regular people's pensions etc... that are being managed by those financial firms.

<sub>Citation: my many years of experience in financial industry including firedrills for events like this (but I am not part of Brexit related extra workload, thankfully).</sub>

Comment: That would make sense if this was a surprise announcement that the UK was going to brexit, but it has been known that brexit would happen for almost a year, and it has been known that it would be by the end of March for a while

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - it wasn't "known". It was likely but not certain. Parlament could have voted "nay". Queen may have vetoed it (is there a verb for denying assent?). Labour could have forced a new re-do referendum. A meteor could have hit.

Comment: Note that "invoking article 50" doesn't mean too much in itself, except making the intention to leave official and setting a two-year limit for the negotiations. It's like announcing that you're going to announcing to prepare leaving the E.U. Don't really see how the financial markets – or anyone else, for that matter – need an announcement to prepare for an announcement?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - that'd be a good question for finance stack, but not sure we got one (may be Quant SE but unlikely... not really a fit on Economics either)

Comment: @user4012 If you really want to play semantics then Ill rephrase... it wasn't 'known' but everyone knew there was a 99.999% chance of it happening. Parliament was never going to vote nay. The Queen does not veto things anymore (remember, figurehead, not real power), Labour did not have the numbers, nor the will, nor the ability to force a new referendum. And a meteor? Really? I suppose we shouldn't have assumed that Trump was going to become president on November 9th.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - was that the same "everyones" who 99.999% knew that REMAIN would win? :) I'm explaining what actually have happened at many institutions had the decision been "tomorrow" - if you don't like that fact, you need to take it up with those institutions' processes, not the messenger.

Comment: @user4012 No one thought 99.999% would remain at the end of Brexit. Also pretty much every MP had made public statements on their voting intentions, so it really was 99.999%. Also, I repeat, every institution has known for almost a year this would happen. if they could not prep for it in a year, they will not be able to do much in 9 days.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - having lived through these firedrills, of course they'll be able to do more in those 9 days than in last year. That's what d eath marches were invented as project management technique for. As I noted in the answer, I know how these things *actually* happen, as opposed to a best theoretical way they *ought to* happen.

Comment: @user4012 Are death marches really an *effective* technique, though?

Comment: @mnbvc - depends on what your end goals are....